# How to remove outer list for arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have this output

```
[array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6])]
```

But I want this output

```
array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6])
```

Comment: Please provide some more details. Output of what?

Comment: `array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6])` are just two arrays floating in space... how should they be contained? In variables?

Comment: I am running LSTM. So after                                                                                   X = np.array(df['Review'])
y = df['Tag']

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
I am getting output like this  [array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6])]                                           But required output is array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6]),array([7,8,9])

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list to a tuple perform following:

```
>>> my_list = [array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6])]
>>> tuple(my_list)
(array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]))
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

While this question is very low on details (what do you mean when you say you want the arrays separately without the list brackets?) I'll attempt to answer it as best as I can.

Based on your comment, the splitting function is supposed to split into a list because that is how you would keep that data but if, for some reason, you want to unpack that list, you can do it in a few ways:

(Also, is this Python 2 or 3?)

(I am going to assuming the list is called arrays)

**Python 2**

1. To display in that format
   `print ', '.join(repr(a) for a in arrays)`
2. To supply them as arguments to some function
   `func(*arrays) #This sends the elements one at a time`

**Python 3**

1. To display in that format

   - `print(', '.join(repr(a) for a in arrays))`
   - `print(*arr, sep=", ")`
2. To supply them as arguments to some function
   `func(*arrays) #This sends the elements one at a time`

These may not be what you want but this is what I figured based on your question.